# "This file requires ARC support"

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started.

I was connected Google according to this tutorial. I put the "Automatic Reference Counting" disabled.

Also "-fno-objc-arc" added. Why would report this error.

```
#error "This file requires ARC support"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. You have disabled ARC support.

The file requires ARC support.

Solution is : re-enable ARC support.